# Ghost onwheel event Javascript with Magic Mouse Apple

Tags: javascript, dom-events, mousewheel

I make a function to handle wheel event on my program.

```
document.onwheel = function(event){
console.log(event);
}
```

I have tested the method on several controllers and browser.

I have a specific problem with the Magic Mouse controller of Apple on Safari and Chrome browser.

When I move mouse with left click pressed (drag and drop with left click button method) and then I remove left click **I receive several wheel event** with "wheelDeltaX" or "deltaX" values.

Answer (score 1):

If you want only a single event emitted from the `wheel` event (i.e. every time the user physically scrolls the wheel on their mouse), then you can use the following method to achieve this:

```js
const element = document.querySelector("#content");
const debounce = 50;
let timeout;

function onMouseWheel(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  element.style.pointerEvents = "none";
  clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(() => {
    element.style.pointerEvents = "auto";
  }, debounce);

  // This will now only log when the user scrolls
  console.log(event.deltaY);
}

element.addEventListener("wheel", onMouseWheel);
```

```css
html, body, #content {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
</div>
```

The code above binds the wheel event to the `#content` div. Once the `wheel` event is fired, all pointer events are immediately disabled for the `#content` div, and then re-enabled after 50ms. This will cause the `wheel` event to fire only one time per scroll, instead of continuously (as it does with the Apple Magic Mouse and other similar momentum scroll devices).

Answer (score 0):

Tested on a classic mouse with windows/chrome browser.
Problem do not appears.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the mouse inertia.

You can disable it in System Preferences > Accessibility > Mouse Options > Scrolling.